# Bind to property inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5

I've got a simple table loop but I can't get the selected radio button to update the property.  I've written this HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let question of questionsFor(category)">
    <td>{{ question.question }}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="{{ question.id }}" [ngModel]="question.pass">Pass
        <input type="radio" value="0" name="{{ question.id }}" [ngModel]="question.pass">Fail
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I hit the submit button and look at the `pass` properties in the questions array, they're all set to `undefined`.

The questions array is just a simple class.

```js
export class SmbwaQuestion {
    id: number;
    question: string;
    pass: number;
}
```

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]="question.pass"`

Comment: Oh jeez. That’s so obvious once you say it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) sometimes it can be too easy and you overlook it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger two way binding, you should use the `[(ngModel)]` notation, otherwise the value does not get updated in the parent component

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="{{ question.id }}" [(ngModel)]="question.pass">Pass
<input type="radio" value="0" name="{{ question.id }}" [(ngModel)]="question.pass">Fail
```